Multiple polygons on the map rnmapbox
I want to display multiple polygons on the map by using rnmapbox. I tried this approach but it showed error Mapbox [error] RNMBXLayer | Layer line seems to refer to an existing layer but existing flag is not specified, this is deprecated
{polygons.map((polygon, index) => (
            <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
              key={index}
              id="source"
              shape={definePolygon(polygon)}
            >
              <MapboxGL.FillLayer
                id="fill"
                style={{
                  fillColor: "grey",
                  fillOpacity: 0.5,
                }}
              />
              <MapboxGL.LineLayer
                id="line"
                style={{ lineColor: "black", lineWidth: 2 }}
              />
            </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
          ))}

Can someone give me an example please because I didnt find anything useful on the internet

Probably you already defined ids you have in these layers: "fill", "line".
Give them unique ids and don't repeat them: "{module}-{purpose}"
      <MapboxGL.FillLayer
        id="my-module-polygon-fill"
        style={{
          fillColor: "grey",
          fillOpacity: 0.5,
        }}
      />
      <MapboxGL.LineLayer
        id="my-module-polygon-line"
        style={{ lineColor: "black", lineWidth: 2 }}
      />

